# Python remove anything that is not a letter or number

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm having a little trouble with Python regular expressions.

What is a good way to remove all characters in a string that are not letters or numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: The string in question contain no ascii character ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`[\w]` matches (alphanumeric or underscore).

`[\W]` matches (not (alphanumeric or underscore)), which is equivalent to (not alphanumeric and not underscore)

You need `[\W_]` to remove ALL non-alphanumerics.

When using re.sub(), it will be much more efficient if you reduce the number of substitutions (expensive) by matching using `[\W_]+` instead of doing it one at a time.

Now all you need is to define alphanumerics:

`str` object, only ASCII A-Za-z0-9:

```
    re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s)
```

`str` object, only locale-defined alphanumerics:

```
    re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s, flags=re.LOCALE)
```

`unicode` object, all alphanumerics:

```
    re.sub(ur'[\W_]+', u'', s, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Examples for `str` object:

```
>>> import re, locale
>>> sall = ''.join(chr(i) for i in xrange(256))
>>> len(sall)
256
>>> re.sub('[\W_]+', '', sall)
'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> re.sub('[\W_]+', '', sall, flags=re.LOCALE)
'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'English_Australia.1252'
>>> re.sub('[\W_]+', '', sall, flags=re.LOCALE)
'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\x83\x8a\x8c\x8e\
x9a\x9c\x9e\x9f\xaa\xb2\xb3\xb5\xb9\xba\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\
xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\
xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\
xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
# above output wrapped at column 80
```

Unicode example:

```
>>> re.sub(ur'[\W_]+', u'', u'a_b A_Z \x80\xFF \u0404', flags=re.UNICODE)
u'abAZ\xff\u0404'
```

Answer (score 10):

In the char set matching rule `[...]` you can specify `^` as first char to mean "not in"

```
import re
re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z]",        # Anything except 0..9, a..z and A..Z
       "",                    # replaced with nothing
       "this is a test!!")    # in this string

--> 'thisisatest'
```

Answer (score 9):

`'\W'` is the same as `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` plus accented chars from your locale.

```
>>> re.sub('\W', '', 'text 1, 2, 3...')
'text123'
```

Maybe you want to keep the spaces or have all the words (and numbers):

```
>>> re.findall('\w+', 'my. text, --without-- (punctuation) 123')
['my', 'text', 'without', 'punctuation', '123']
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax
you forgot the `_`. 
\w == [^a-zA-Z0-9_]

Answer (score 4):

Also you can try to use isalpha and isnumeric methods the following way:

```
text = 'base, sample test;'
getVals = lambda x: (c for c in text if c.isalpha() or c.isnumeric())
map(lambda word: ' '.join(getVals(word)): text.split(' '))
```

Comment: or the more succinct `isalnum()` method!  though the OP does ask for a regex

Comment: I have decided to post my solution here just only because i like to have several ways of how to solve any task - so i simply suppose that author also probably would like to have another option. Sorry if i am wrong

Comment: Ultimately, the purpose of our answers is to try to be helpful.  If you think it would be helpful to use a string method rather than a regular expression (and this is often the case in Python), then it isn't wrong to mention it.

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways also you may consider e.g. simply loop thru string and skip unwanted chars e.g. assuming you want to delete all ascii chars which are not letter or digits

```
>>> newstring = [c for c in "a!1#b$2c%3\t\nx" if c in string.letters + string.digits]
>>> "".join(newstring)
'a1b2c3x'
```

or use string.translate to map one char to other or delete some chars e.g.

```
>>> todelete = [ chr(i) for i in range(256) if chr(i) not in string.letters + string.digits ]
>>> todelete = "".join(todelete)
>>> "a!1#b$2c%3\t\nx".translate(None, todelete)
'a1b2c3x'
```

this way you need to calculate `todelete` list once or `todelete` can be hard-coded once and use it everywhere you need to convert string

Answer (score 1):

you can use predefined regex in python : `\W` corresponds to the set `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Then,

```
import re
s = 'Hello dutrow 123'
re.sub('\W', '', s)
--> 'Hellodutrow123'
```

Comment: What about the non-ASCII world? Also, doesn't remove underscore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific:

1. What about Unicode "letters"? ie, those with diacriticals.
2. What about white space? (I assume this is what you DO want to delete along with punctuation)
3. When you say "letters" do you mean `A-Z` and `a-z` in ASCII only?
4. When you say "numbers" do you mean `0-9` only? What about decimals, separators and exponents?

It gets complex quickly...

A great place to start is an interactive regex site, such as [RegExr](http://regexr.com?2tvo5)

You can also get Python specific [Python Regex Tool](http://www.pythonregex.com/)