# Split strings containing multiple delimiters

Tags: python, string, split

I need to split following string:

```
str1 = "0020 04,5",3
```

expected output is:

```
['0020 04,5', '3']
```

What I tried was

```
print [p for p in re.split('(|".+?"|,|)', a) if p.strip()]
```

Comment: What are the characters you'd like to split on?

Comment: Why is the expected output `['0020 04,5', '3']`? What are these multiple delimiters?

Comment: Maybe you can split for everything which is not a letter or digit. For this see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6325804/2894316)

Comment: `str1 = "0020 04,5",3` is _not_ valid Python _string_, please give an actual example.

Comment: @Selcuk - Sure it is. It's a `tuple` with `'0020 04,5'` as the first element and `3` as the second. I mean, it's not an appropriate argument to send to `re.split()`, but it's perfectly valid Python per se.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You are right, but I am right too :)

Comment: So you have a `tuple` consisting of a string and an integer.  It looks like you want to convert it to a list, with all elements convert to strings?  You can use `map(str, str1)` to achieve that.  Or did you in fact intend something different for `str1`, such as an actual, single string?  If so, then *fix your post*.

Comment: @Borja - `("0020 04,5", 3)` is _a_ correct syntax, but the parentheses and whitespace can be omitted. Try `str1 = "0020 04,5",3` in an interpreter. Works fine. Again, it's not a suitable object to send to `re.split()`, which is probably what Selcuk meant, but I just don't want anyone to get the impression that you'll get a nice loud traceback if you try `str1 = "0020 04,5",3`, because you won't, as it's valid code.

Comment: list(str1) doeas the trick

Comment: @YOBA No, that fails to convert the `3` to a string.

Comment: @TomKarzes Right, didn't see that ! then [ str(x) for x in str1 ] should be fine !

Comment: @YOBA Or, as I said earlier, `map(str, str1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to a list:

```
str1 = ['"0020 04,5",3']
```

and use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
>>> from csv import reader
>>> for line in reader(str1):
...     print line
... 
['0020 04,5', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[]

for x in str:

   a.append(x)

print a

['0020 04,5', 3]
```

**Another way**:

```
[a.append(x) for x in str]
```

Comment: The last `3` should be a string, not an int.