# keep all alphabetic and numeric characters in python

Tags: python-3.x

i have a file.txt and i just want to keep all alphabetic and numeric characters without whitespace and save it in a list, is there another way to do it? 
this is the new code, is faster. what do you think about it?

```
fin = open(fcompiti, encoding = 'UTF-8')
s = fin.read()
s = s.replace(' ', '').replace('\n','')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a little fast:

```
import re, string

pattern = re.compile('[\W_]+')

with open('file.txt') as f:
    rdstr = f.read()

rdstr = pattern.sub('', rdstr)

print(rdstr)
```

For this txt file:

```
abc342][][]asde34=)$(s)
```

it will return

```
abc342asde34s
```

You can watch it in live here https://repl.it/Ni04/0

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a regex, which may or may not be faster than your approach (depending on the size and structure of your text).

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()

s = ''.join(re.findall(r'[\dA-z]+', s))
```

As a side note, your code is not as memory efficient as it could be. Instead of creating a list in memory and then passing it to `join` you can use a generator.

```
s = ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha() or c.isnumeric())
# note absence of square brackets
```

Comment: Nice one! At first I thought in check char by char, but then I saw your answer and remember the power of regex

Answer (score 1):

[Regex (regular expressions)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are your friend.

```
fin = open('file.txt')
s = fin.read()
alphanums = re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6325804) answer will give you more knowledge and examples on how and why this works.

Comment: aaah that's great, we post similar at the same time, it's a plus one :D

Answer (score 0):

outside of using RegEx, you could also use the [`.isalnum()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isalnum.htm) builtin function instead of checking `.isalpha()` and `.isnumeric()`

```
with open('file.txt') as fin:
    s = fin.read()
    s = ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalnum())
```

EDIT: as another user mentioned, you can remove the part that is creating a list of the characters in the file before joining them. the `[`, `]` brackets inside of the `.join()` aren't necessary.

Comment: This answer is the same speed as the code already provided. MISTERCEC specifically asked for a faster solution than the one they provided

Comment: when testing this myself on a large file, it is faster. it's only evaluating 1 expression rather than 2. the speed problems he's facing are more than likely because of how big his files are, which there isn't really any solution to. so i provided a solution that helps the string parsing at least a little bit.